# MYSQL query: Undefined offset: 2

Tags: php

```
$tsvhandle = fopen($tsvfile, 'r'); 
while (($data = fgetcsv($tsvhandle, 1000, ";")) !== FALSE) {
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT `post_id` FROM `charvest_postmeta` WHERE `meta_key` = '_sku' AND `meta_value` = '".$data[2]."'") or die($result."<br/><br/>".mysql_error());
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
        echo $row['post_id']. "</br>";

    }
}
```

I receive " PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 2", but I don't understand what's the problem. Please help to me to fix that.

Thank you!

Comment: $data[2] does not exist, what is in fgetcsv() ?

Comment: I can print $data[2]. It's a CSV file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$data` just don't have 3rd column (indexed 2) on some iteration.

You can check that within a loop: `if (!isset($data[2])) { ...`

Comment: $data[2] exists, I can print it, but it's not working inside the mysql query. $data is a csv file, but I had to rebuild it.

Comment: If you have the notice, it means there is at least one row where `$data[2]` does not exist. Maybe an empty line at the end ?

Comment: Yes, there was an empty line. Thank you!